# Devexpress How to change progress bar control color

Tags: c#, devexpress, progress-bar, devexpress-windows-ui

Can someone tell me that how to change backcolor of progress bar control. I am using devexpress bar control. I have searched and tried the ways which are explained on devexpress forum and this site.[progress bar back color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovGlZ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ProgressBarControl.Property.LookAndFeel.Style` is set to `Skin`, the control's background is fully controlled by the current skin.
The progress bar appearance can be customized via the `Properties.StartColor` and `EndColor` properties.
Change `LookAndFeel` to anything except `UseDefaultLookAndFeel` that will work.